# Excel VB Listbox losing Value and Text Property

Tags: excel, properties, listbox, vba

I'm trying to solve this problem along 2 days but I've not found the solution.
I have a lot of listboxes on my excel and each of these listboxes are filled with different data, also I use these listboxes to change some filters at a pivot table using a VB code.

The problem is that after some usage these listboxes stop to work, they stop to get the values that are selected. 
I've discovered that two properties, 'Value' and 'Text' has been disappeared after the problem happened. To use the listboxes again I need to close excel and open it again, also if I try to save the workbook, it stop to work.

I've tried to bring some images of it, but I got no reputation yet.

Who can help me?

Updating:

Here is the images:

[image]

[image]

And here is the code behind the listboxes (all listboxes has a similar code):

```
If ListFaturaFatura.List(ListFaturaFatura.ListIndex) = "Total" Or _
ListFaturaFatura.List(ListFaturaFatura.ListIndex) = "" Then
    Sheets("Fatura_Data").PivotTables("DinamicaFatura1").PivotFields("FATURA").ClearAllFilters
Else
    Sheets("Fatura_Data").PivotTables("DinamicaFatura1").PivotFields("FATURA").CurrentPage = _
    ListFaturaFatura.List(ListFaturaFatura.ListIndex)
End If
```

Also, I think that is an excel problem, because when it happens all workbooks are affected with the same problem.

Comment: May I see the workbook? If yes, then please upload it in a free file sharing site and share the link here. If not then please upload the images in a free file sharing site and share the link here. We will update the question. Also you may want to update the question with the code revolving around listboxes?

Comment: Ok, I can't upload the file because it's a corporate file, but I've uploaded the listbox properties image and the code behind the listboxes.

Comment: Any idea? I need to finish this work until the end of next week and I don't know how I will fix this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like so sort of corruption to me. I could be wrong though.

Comment: It's not clear to me. If it's a kind of corruption at the workbook, where may I start to look? 
I've already checked that the problem starts after 10 times that I use the listboxes. It seems to be a stupid problem, but it's driving me crazy.

Comment: Can you delete those listboxes and rebuild them?

Comment: Yes, I can do it, but you think should I delete all listboxes from the workbook?

Comment: I apparently solved the problem, I was about to delete all listboxes and create it again, but I saw that one of the listboxes I was filling with a named range, I did remove this named range and filled the listbox manually, this seems to solve the problem.
I'll test it until the end of day and them I update here with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that one of the listboxes was filled with a named range, I just removed the named range and filled the listbox manually, this seems to work fine and didn't give me more problems.